# Proper way to say "it looks good"

Tags: expressions, spoken-language

Let's say you're at the barber shop and he's using his mirror to show you how your hair looks like after he's done cutting it, what would be the appropriate and natural way to say "It looks good (thank you)"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My observation from having been to the barber a few hundred times in Japan since birth, People would rarely, if not never, say anything so unique or lengthy in that situation.  Most would just say:

「これでいいです。」

「いいです。」

「オッケーです。」

「大丈夫{だいじょうぶ}です。」

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on your personality and your degree of satisfaction.

Me, and the majority of people would probably answer :

> 大丈夫です

When asked

> どうですか？

Another way to say it looks good is

> よさそう

If you are upbeat and expressive, you could say something like :

> いいですね！

Comment: You do mean どうですか rather than 同ですか, right?

Comment: @Blavius wow, sorry about that... My keyboard automatically inputted that kanji... That's weird, It's rare for the keyboard to be wrong... Especially when one option is 100 times more common than the other...

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to your flavor or your cup of tea. According to your words: It looks good (this sounds you are not going to compliment or denounce him.)

- こんな/いい 感じ
- 決まりましたね
- バッチリです (I have no idea where this word came from, but it means 'perfect')
- 上出来/上等 (Compare to my face, haircut is way too good, a little humble)

  These are appropriate for a normal and casual relation with the barber.

Comment: What would be appropriate if I wanted to show a bit more praise and appreciation?

Comment: 流石ですね/思った以上です would include compliments, and I wrote them in order to express appreciation on my answer up to down, but those words are getting far from "it looks good". It sounds "fantastic work!"